# Is it possible to redirect from one page in Project A to a page in Project B from within the same solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to redirect from one page in Project A to page in Project B with in same solution.Here the Project A is in C# and Project B In VB.

Is it possible? If so, can anyone then tell me of any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to let project A know the base URL under which project B is running, probably via a setting in the Web.config file. There's no simple shortcut way just because they're in the same solution.

Comment: When i am running the application with direct path
(Project B + Page Name) its not working....

Comment: You need to not use a file system path, but a URL where project B is hosted. This is likely to be of the form `http://localhost:xxxx/path`.